# Mysqldump simple batch issue

Tags: batch-file, mysql

I am trying to write a simple batch file to run a MySqlDump.  I created a new file in notepad, pasted the text below, and then saved it as a bat file.  However when I attempt to run this in command prompt the screen pops up right away and then goes away just as fast.  If I run these commands manually in command prompt it works as expected.

This is my first bat file I have created so I'm guessing I am doing something wrong?  In looking at similar issues in StackOverflow the code below appears to be what is suggested so I'm confused why this isn't working?

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxx --all-databases --single-transaction > C:\Users\JMaze\Desktop\nSite\MySQL Backup\bk.sql
```

Comment: C:\Users...\MySQL Backup\bk.sql isn't a legal file path. `...` is only valid on Win 9x.

Comment: Sorry, that ... isn't what is in the actual code, I just wanted to blank out the actual path since it wasn't relevant.  The actual path is C:\Users\JMaze\Desktop\nSite\MySQL Backup\bk.sql

Comment: Put pause on last line and read the error message.

Comment: The path have to be quoted if the `SPACE` in it.  `"C:\Users\JMaze\Desktop\nSite\MySQL Backup\bk.sql"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding the quotes to each of the file paths appears to have fixed the issue.  The final code looks like this:

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxx --all-databases --single-transaction > "C:\Users\JMaze\Desktop\nSite\MySQL Backup\bk.sql"